# How does Ruby's Enumerator object iterate externally over an internal iterator?

Tags: ruby, iterator, enumerator

As per Ruby's documentation, the Enumerator object uses the `each` method (to enumerate) if no target method is provided to the `to_enum` or `enum_for` methods. Now, let's take the following monkey patch and its enumerator, as an example

```
o = Object.new
def o.each
    yield 1
    yield 2
    yield 3
end
e = o.to_enum

loop do
  puts e.next
end
```

Given that the Enumerator object uses the `each` method to answer when `next` is called, how do calls to the `each` method look like, every time `next` is called? Does the Enumeartor class pre-load all the contents of `o.each` and creates a local copy for enumeration? Or is there some sort of Ruby magic that hangs the operations at each yield statement until `next` is called on the enumeartor?

If an internal copy is made, is it a deep copy? What about I/O objects that could be used for external enumeration?

I'm using Ruby 1.9.2.

Comment: Just so you know, you use backticks ( \` ) around text to do inline code formatting `:)`

Comment: muchas gracias! Will keep that in mind for next time.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's not exactly magic, but it is beautiful nonetheless. Instead of making a copy of some sort, a [`Fiber`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Fiber.html) is used to first execute `each` on the target enumerable object. After receiving the next object of `each`, the `Fiber` yields this object and thereby returns control back to where the `Fiber` was resumed initially.

It's beautiful because this approach doesn't require a copy or other form of "backup" of the enumerable object, as one could imagine obtaining by for example calling `#to_a` on the enumerable. The cooperative scheduling with fibers allows to switch contexts exactly when needed without the need to keep some form of lookahead.

It all happens in the [C code](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/enumerator.c#L546-L605) for `Enumerator`. A pure Ruby version that would show roughly the same behavior could look like this:

```
class MyEnumerator
  def initialize(enumerable)
    @fiber = Fiber.new do
      enumerable.each { |item| Fiber.yield item }
    end
  end

  def next
    @fiber.resume || raise(StopIteration.new("iteration reached an end"))
  end
end

class MyEnumerable
  def each
    yield 1
    yield 2
    yield 3
  end
end

e = MyEnumerator.new(MyEnumerable.new)
puts e.next # => 1
puts e.next # => 2
puts e.next # => 3
puts e.next # => StopIteration is raised
```

Comment: Nice! I'll read up on fibers in more detail, but are these green threads created by the language to return control to the caller? In other words how is control returned?

Comment: @SalmanParacha [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiber_(computer_science)) does a better job at explaining the difference than I ever could. If you want the gory details, the implementation is in [cont.c](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/cont.c).

Comment: @SalmanParacha: Fibers are Ruby's name for coroutines. A coroutine is a generalization of a subroutine: a subroutine *always* starts to run from the beginning, and it *always* returns back to the caller. A coroutine runs from the point where it was last stopped and it can "return" (or more precisely transfer control) to *any* other coroutine, not just the one where it came from.

Comment: @Casper: Think I know what you mean :) The implementation has an effective "lookahead" of one item.

Comment: @emboss Yes..right. Sorry I deleted the comment though. I realized I tested it only on the ruby 1.8 native implementation, and have not tested it actually with ruby 1.9 and Fiber. But I would assume it works the same there.

Comment: `to_a`, `map`, and all the other methods for enumerators are all also defined in terms of `each` right? From this answer, what I got is that `next` uses `each` internally just like the other iterator methods but uses a `Fiber` to maintain state. Is this correct?