# Methods with blocks - how to calculate arrays together - ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, methods, block

I want to create a method that uses a block to calculate the sum between 2 arrays in this manner; [1,2,3] + [2,4,6] = [3,6,9].

This is what I have so far, and the error I get tells me I have the wrong number of arguments.

*edit. I must use a method and a block to carry this out

```
def arraycalc(x,y) 
    yield x,y 
end

arraycalc([1,2,3], [2,4,6]){|x,y| x+y}  
p arraycalc #[3,6,9]
```

I am still new in Ruby. Can someone please tell me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement it like this

```
def arraycalc a, b
 a.zip(b).map {|x, y| yield x, y}
end

p arraycalc([1,2], [3,4]) {|x, y| x + y}
#=> [4, 6]
```

Comment: Thank you!! Could you explain what the zip does exactly? I am very bad at reading code. Also, is there a more basic way of doing this without the zip?

Comment: @basukesu: you could try reading [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-zip) for zip.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I will do so. Thank you very much!

Comment: @basukesu: You could simply loop through the array with an index and do `yield a[i], b[i]` though that's not very ruby-like.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `Array#zip` method:

```
[1, 2, 3].zip([2, 3, 4]).map { |x, y| x + y } # => [3, 5, 7]
```

**Update:**

```
def arraycalc(array1,array2)
  result_array = array1.zip(array2)
  result_array.map { |x, y| yield x,y } if block_given?
end

arraycalc([1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]) { |x, y| x + y } # => [3, 5, 7]
```

Comment: thank you! However, I need to use a method and a block to do this because that is what the homework says. Do you know any other way to do this?

Comment: @basukesu: extract the zip/map part into a method, and pass the block to it.

Comment: @basukesu: You could use a Fiber. The posting [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11057223/how-does-rubys-enumerator-object-iterate-externally-over-an-internal-iterator) gives an example from which you can derive your own solution.

Comment: @user1934428: what are the benefits of using a fiber here?

Comment: @SergeiStralenia Thank you. This helps! But I don't truly understand the zip. Is there an alternative?

Comment: @basukesu, try zip method in irb, and you will undestand how it works:)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: A Fiber is one (not the only one!) way to create a generator without needing to create a temporary array. The OP was looking for a solution, where he wanted to write his own method, and wanted to use a block argument, and using a fiber would be a possible solution. I think this thread turns into a list of different ways to kill the same cat. BTW, do you see a disadvantage in using a fiber?

Comment: @user1934428: disadvantage there is extra complexity for no reason whatsoever.

Answer (score 3):

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]

require 'matrix'

(Vector[*a] + Vector[*b]).to_a #=> [5,7,9]
```

or

```
(Matrix[a] + Matrix[b]).to_a   #=> [5,7,9]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[[1,2,3],[2,4,6]].transpose.map{|a| a.sum}
```

[3,6,9]

Comment: Thank you! is there a way I can do this using a method an a block?

Comment: Ruby does not have a method `Array#sum`. (No Rails tag.) You need `...map { |a| a.reduce(:+) }`.